# Two if statements with the same judgment object will casue conflict in Verilog?

Tags: verilog

This is the code:

```
always@(posedge clk_29 or negedge rstn) begin
    if(!rstn) cnt <= 4'd0;
    else if(!sw_i[0])
    begin
        tmp = 7'b0000000;
        cnt = 4'd0;
    end
    else if(sw_i[0])
    begin
       case(cnt)
        4'b0000:tmp=7'b0111111;
        4'b0001:tmp=7'b0000110;
        4'b0010:tmp=7'b1011011;
        4'b0011:tmp=7'b1001111;
        4'b0100:tmp=7'b1100110;
        4'b0101:tmp=7'b1101101;
        4'b0110:tmp=7'b1111101;
        4'b0111:tmp=7'b0000111;
       endcase
       cnt = cnt + 1;
       
       if(cnt > 4'b0111) cnt = 4'b0000;
    end
  end
```

In reality, the sw_i[0] is a button, and the tmp is a LED.
In this code, I can control signal sw_i[0].
The expected result is when I turn sw_i[0] on, it can make cnt + 1 and make LED display different number. When I turn sw_i[0] off, it can make LED turn off and make cnt 0.
However, when I turn the button on, it can work normally. However, when I turn the button off, the LED just display the last number (not turn off) and when I turn the button on, the number just increase it by the last number, which means the code between `if(!sw_i[0])` not work.

And what I try is just change `else if(!sw_i[0])` to `else if(!sw_i[1])`, which can work!
PS: sw_i[1] is another button.
So I am wondering if there is any conflict in between two if statement which is about the same port(sw_i[0]) in the always@.

This is the completed code if you need:

```
module mytask(
    input[15:0] sw_i,
    output[7:0] disp_an_o,
    output[6:0] disp_seg_o,
    input wire rstn,
    input wire clk
    );
    
    parameter div_para = 24;
    reg [31:0] count;
    reg [6:0] tmp;
    reg [3:0] cnt;
    wire clk_29;
    
    assign disp_an_o = ~8'b11111111;
    always@(posedge clk or negedge rstn) begin
    if(!rstn) count <= 0;
    else if(!sw_i[0]) count <= 0;
    else if(sw_i[0])
         count <= count + 1;
    end
    
    assign clk_29 = count[div_para];
    always@(posedge clk_29 or negedge rstn) begin
    if(!rstn) cnt <= 4'd0;
    else if(!sw_i[0])
    begin
        tmp = 7'b0000000;
        cnt = 4'd0;
    end
    else if(sw_i[0])
    begin
       case(cnt)
        4'b0000:tmp=7'b0111111;
        4'b0001:tmp=7'b0000110;
        4'b0010:tmp=7'b1011011;
        4'b0011:tmp=7'b1001111;
        4'b0100:tmp=7'b1100110;
        4'b0101:tmp=7'b1101101;
        4'b0110:tmp=7'b1111101;
        4'b0111:tmp=7'b0000111;
       endcase
       cnt = cnt + 1;
       
       if(cnt > 4'b0111) cnt = 4'b0000;
    end
  end
  assign disp_seg_o = ~tmp;
endmodule
```

Comment: without a reproducible example, you need to be extremely detailed in what you mean by "can work" and "does not work". What do you expect to happen versus what you actually see happening. Also, "code that I written will not be carried out." specifically which code?

Comment: @dave_59. Thank you for your tip and I update it.

Comment: there is no testbench, apparently you have not simulated it. Most likely, your design is supposed to work as you described, but without simulation it is difficult to figure it out.  Also without testbench, its impossible for the forum to try your code. You have a pretty large divisor in your clock divider. So, it could take very long time to get to the next posedge of it.  Have you checked your clocks?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is only visible with the complete code. Your clock divider is looking at sw_i[0]. So when you turn off the switch, you are also turning off clk_29.

It should just be

```
always@(posedge clk or negedge rstn)
  if(!rstn) count <= 0;
    else 
  count <= count + 1;
```